# Acceder a datos de DropDownList dentro de GridView ASP

Tags: asp, gridview, dropdownlist

Tengo un GridView en una página ASPX que crea filas con DropDownList que se llenan dependiendo el elemento que aparezca en dicha fila.
Los puedo llenar sin problema, el problema viene cuando quiero leer el dato seleccionado en cada DropdownList, de la manera que lo he hecho me muestra como si siempre eligiera el primer item, he probado de muchas maneras pero no logro hacer que me lea el dato correcto. Alguna sugerencia?

Este es mi código ASP del Grid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GRIDcomponentes" runat="server" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" GridLines="Both" Width="100%" BackColor="White" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Code"
                                  OnRowDataBound="GRIDcomponentes_OnRowDataBound" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" OnRowDeleting="GRIDcomponentes_OnRowDeleting" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" class="gridComp">
                       <Columns>

                           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Código">  
                               <EditItemTemplate>  
                                   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Code") %>'/>  
                               </EditItemTemplate>  
                               <ItemTemplate>  
                                   <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Code") %>'/>  
                               </ItemTemplate>  
                           </asp:TemplateField>
                           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nombre">  
                               <EditItemTemplate>  
                                   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ItemName") %>'/>  
                               </EditItemTemplate>  
                               <ItemTemplate>  
                                   <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ItemName") %>'/>  
                               </ItemTemplate>  
                           </asp:TemplateField>
                           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cantidad">  
                               <EditItemTemplate>  
                                   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Quantity") %>'></asp:TextBox>  
                               </EditItemTemplate>  
                               <ItemTemplate>  
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCantidad" class="justNumbers" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Quantity") %>' OnTextChanged="txtCantidad_OnTextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                               </ItemTemplate>  
                           </asp:TemplateField>
                           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Lote">  
                               <EditItemTemplate>  
                                   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Lote") %>'></asp:TextBox>  
                               </EditItemTemplate> 
                               <ItemTemplate>  
                                   <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLloteArt" runat="server" class="loteArticulo" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDLloteArt_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="False" />
                               </ItemTemplate>  
                           </asp:TemplateField>

                       </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

En mi CodeBehind, al hacerle el binding al GRID, tengo esto en mi evento OnRowDataBound, para llenar el DropDownList con los datos que le correspondan.

```
protected void GRIDcomponentes_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e){
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                string id1 = GRIDcomponentes.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
                TextBox txt1 = e.Row.FindControl("txtCantidad") as TextBox;

                DataSet ds = CspModel.spObtieneLoteDisponible(id1, Int32.Parse(txt1.Text), Session["almacen"].ToString()); //Aquí trae los datos con los que se llena ese DDL

                DropDownList dd1 = (e.Row.FindControl("DDLloteArt") as DropDownList);
                dd1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                dd1.DataValueField = "Lote";
                dd1.DataTextField = "Lote";
                dd1.DataBind();

            }
}
```

Todo eso me da una vista como esta:
[image: GridView]

Todo esto funciona bien, pero el problema es leer los datos que se seleccionaron en cada DDL. Lo hago de esta manera en el botón para Añadir:

```
 protected void BTNadd_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e){
 string[] LotesSel = new string[GRIDcomponentes.Rows.Count];
            int count = 0;
            //Comprobamos que todos tengan lotes seleccionados
            string lote = string.Empty;
            int loteN;
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GRIDcomponentes.Rows){
                lote = ((DropDownList)row.FindControl("DDLloteArt")).SelectedItem.Value;
                loteN = ((DropDownList)row.FindControl("DDLloteArt")).SelectedIndex;
                LotesSel[count] = lote;
                count++;
             }
}
```

Trato de leer el valor de todos los DropDownList y guardarlos en el array de `LotesSel`, pero ya sea con `Value` o con `SelectedIndex`siempre me trae como si tuviera seleccionado el primer elemento o el Index 0.

¿Alguna ayuda o recomendación? He intentado de muchas maneras y no logro dar con la solución.

Comment: ¿Te hace un doble postback? pon un punto de ruptura en el page load para comprobarlo, si hace doble postback pasará dos veces. En la primera tiene el valor del selected item y en la segunta no.

Comment: @Jnavero No, no me hace doble postback, pasa directo a la función del botón de `BTNadd_OnClick` y después hace el PostBack.
Al recorrer la función instrucción por instrucción con un punto de interrupción, si lee el número de DDL que existen (pe. si hay 3 filas, encuentra 3 ddl, si hay 5 encuentra 5, etc), pero siempre me trae el valor por default.

Comment: Sería interesante saber ese de que "después" hace el postback. ¿En ese después tu lista tiene el valor? ¿Puede ser que el control use algun tipo de ajax y la lista no tenga el valor correspondiente? Son solo pensamientos y sugerencias por que es dificil saber que te está pasando. Saludos.